# How is this SQL Server PK violation possible?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, primary-key

I'm getting an error that I thought was impossible. I have a SQL Server (ver 11.0.6594) table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [IDMaster](
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IDMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It's basically supposed to do what the IDENTITY does now (it's been around a while) – it is used to get new unique integer values, that are used in a few other tables.

Now I have a SQL statement, which selects the MAX value, adds to it, and INSERTs that value into the same table – all inside one statement. So in theory, it's not possible to get a PK violation on this statement (although I think could possibly get a deadlock). But, somehow, it *is* getting one.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_IDMaster'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'IDMaster'. The duplicate key value is (25309587).

I don't know how this is possible, but apparently it is; because it just happened.

Imagine any crazy, odd mixture of other ways to try generating a new ID value from this same table, and they probably aren't far off from what exists in this system. But I can't think of any way that they could cause that particular error. It was my understanding that the transaction locking used by SQL Server enforces that, within one SQL statement that doesn't have (NOLOCK) on it or anything, there *can't* be any interference with the rows that it is referencing.

The only other factor, which I don't think could be related but who knows, is that this SQL is wrapped in a TRY, with some options set. Here's the SQL that got that error:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO IDMaster (ID) 
 SELECT COALESCE(
  -- make sure the new value is odd
  CASE WHEN MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) % 2 = 0
   THEN MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) + 1
   ELSE MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) + 2
   END,1)
 FROM IDMaster;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  WHILE (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK;
  THROW;
END CATCH
WHILE (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) COMMIT;
```

Please explain:

1. How is it possible to get that error?
2. If possible, how can I prevent it from ever happening (without altering the table)?

Comment: Yes, there are several different service that generate a new ID value. My service is just one of them. The others use different (worse) methods to generate a new ID value. Re-engineering this table used by these several services is not an option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your theory is wrong.  Reading from your "identity" table doesn't lock it, the insert into it locks it.  While they are part of a single compound statement, they are still seperate actions. Two (or more) connections can be reading from the table during the time between the read and the insert.  The insert uses a lock, so only one of the connections will actually be able to write the value they read into the table, other connections, will, as you have discovered, get a primary key violation error.

The best solution is to use one of the builtin methods for handling this: identity columns, sequences, or guids.  Roll your own solutions should generally be avoided: you simply don't have the experience or user base that the database management systems do (and you are dealing with an abstraction, so even if you were one of the programmers for one of the major database management systems, you wouldn't be able to do the same kind of things).

Comment: Thanks. I agree, but it's not my table to ALTER, so I can't do that. I will have to either apply some type of locking, or add "retry" logic.

Answer (score 28):

> Now I have a SQL statement, which selects the MAX value, adds to it, and INSERTs that value into the same table -- all inside one statement. So in theory, it's not possible to get a PK violation on this statement (although I think could possibly get a deadlock). But, somehow, it IS getting one.

It definitely *IS* possible. This is due to your isolation level and how locking works.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_IDMaster'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'IDMaster'. The duplicate key value is (25309587).

This is due to locking; initially in the read committed isolation level will take a shared lock on the (in this case) key while reading what the maximum value is. After it figures it out, an X lock will be needed to insert into the table. That's the simple overview of it.

When you have a single session, this isn't a problem. When you have multiple sessions this is a *huge* problem as shared locks are compatible with each other. This means that multiple readers can obtain the same value.

> don't know how this is possible, but apparently it is; because it just happened.

See above.

### So How Do You Fix It?

1. Don't try to be smarter than SQL Server. Use the available constructs that fit the need - in SQL Server 2012 (major version 11) has both identity and sequences. Use them.
2. Purposely kill your concurrency by either using serializable or lock hints such as XLOCK. This will on purpose block other sessions which means you'll have less performance... and you're doing it on purpose... so yeah that seems bad but a possible solution.
3. Pre-create values (again trying to be smarter than SQL Server) and use XLOCK + READPAST to get a little better concurrency from a different table. Blah. Let me reiterate #1, don't try to be smarter than SQL Server [in this case].

Comment: I agree in theory, but you're violating the premise of the question -- "without altering the table".

Comment: @Abacus No, #2 and #3 answer that part. It's terrible, but it's an answer given you don't want to fix the actual issue but more have it work at all costs without changing anything even if that means grinding all work to halt.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method for serializing access to a section of code is [application locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql).

The downside is it requires marginally more development work. The upside is
multiple statements can be inside the applock scope, preventing deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there are multiple interactions with the table, your select is not locking the data, only the insert is.

To achieve what you're asking you need to lock the latest row that you are using to prevent something else from reading it as well (as others have said this will significantly reduce your throughput - you're blocking concurrent throughput).

Suggest using some [table hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?msclkid=5613ba32b03a11ecb346c9a4c6a96a00&view=sql-server-ver15) to specify the type of lock you are taking:

- **ROWLOCK** : Lock only the last row (you don't need to lock the whole table)
- **XLOCK** : Lock that row for exclusive use by your transaction

This means you can have another process reading from your table (old rows), and only processes that are using XLOCK will wait until the row has been released.

Option 1: Example using a full transaction

```
DECLARE @NextID INT

BEGIN TRAN
    /* Find the last row and lock it to determine your next ID */
    SELECT @NextID = COALESCE(
        -- make sure the new value is odd
        CASE WHEN MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) % 2 = 0
            THEN MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) + 1
            ELSE MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) + 2
        END,1)
    FROM IDMaster WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK)

    /* insert the ID back into the IDENTITY table */
    INSERT INTO IDMaster (ID) VALUES (@NextID)

COMMIT TRAN

/* Return the ID that you created for this call, this return doesn't need to be part of the transaction */
SELECT @NextID as ID
```

Option 2: Still do it in a nice clean transaction but as a single 'statement'

```
INSERT INTO IDMaster (ID) 
SELECT COALESCE(
    -- make sure the new value is odd
    CASE WHEN MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) % 2 = 0
        THEN MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) + 1
        ELSE MAX(COALESCE(ID,0)) + 2
    END,1)
FROM IDMaster WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK);
```

*Notes: As others have pointed out this is a BAD design, there are much much better options available in SQL Server (use [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?msclkid=5c13886cb03e11eca95d559976a547ce&view=sql-server-ver15) or [SEQUENCE NUMBERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15))*, however you asked how it could be done and are dealing with a lot of organizational constraints and it deserves a more complete answer.

Answer (score -4):

This is only a partial answer -- I figured out the "how to fix" thanks another DBA. The solution is to use

```
WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

Comment: And there goes your concurrency. Seriously, the best approach is to abandon your table and start using a sequence.

Comment: Please explain *why* before you downvote. And consider reading the context of the question. If someone asks how to fix their car, saying "buy a new car" is *not* an answer to that question. In my scenario, even an "80% solution" is preferable than "spend days talking to others, to ask them to spend weeks of their time rewriting code, which they don't think is broken"

Comment: The votes may reflect the suitability of this answer for other people finding this Q & A in future (who are unlikely to face the same restrictions as you). People are probably voting on the general idea, so don't take it personally.

Comment: Good point Paul, thanks. Yes, in this case I am in a very specific area that I really hope others will avoid. So even if I can't get out of it, I gladly accept the negative votes, on the basis that others might be able to use this to improve their own situation. :)

Answer (score -4):

Dirty reads are DIRTY Reads.  You need to lock the table on the read and remove the lock after a successful insert.

Comment: Where did you get the idea dirty reads are involved, Jim?